# rules for use reg exp java

Tags: java, regex

i have pattern:

```
host=([a-z0-9./:]*)
```

it's find for me host address. And i have `content`

`host=http//:sdf3452.domain.com/`

And my code is:

```
    Matcher m;
    Pattern hostP = Pattern.compile("host=([a-z0-9./:]*)");
    m=hostP.matcher(content);//string 1
    String match = m.group();//string 2 
    Log.i("host", ""+hostP.matcher(content).find());
```

if i delete string 1 and 2 i see `true` in `logcat`. If left as is I got exception nothing found.
I've tried all kinds of `pattern`. Through debug looked `m` variable, finds no match. Please teach me use reg exp!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you `group()` a match, you need to invoke `find()`.

Try it like this:

```
Pattern hostP = Pattern.compile("host=([a-z0-9./:]*)");
Matcher m = hostP.matcher(content);

if(m.find()) {
  String match = m.group();
  // ... 
}
```

### EDIT

and a little demo that shows what each match-group contains:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("host=([a-z0-9./:]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("host=http://sdf3452.domain.com/");
if (m.find()) {
  for(int i = 0; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.printf("m.group(%d) = '%s'\n", i, m.group(i));
  }
}
```

which will print:

```
m.group(0) = 'host=http://sdf3452.domain.com/'
m.group(1) = 'http://sdf3452.domain.com/'
```

As you can see, group(0), which is the same as `group()`, contains what the entire pattern matches.

But realize that a URL can contain much more than what your defined in `[a-z0-9./:]*`!

Comment: Also `.` is a special regex character which means any character. You have to escape it like: `host=([a-z0-9\./:]*)`

Comment: @m0skit0, no, a `.` is not special inside a character class.

Comment: `group()` will return what was matched/found by the whole expression, I suspect it should be `group(1)` to return what was matched by the capturing-group - the value after the equals

Comment: Sorry for not reply so long. My problem is inattention. I did not know what i must call find(). Thanks for a detailed answer! If you only knew how I was angry at myself for these regular expression. Eclipse IDE with new ADT often in conflict. I do not know why. But greatly complicate a comfortable work. With the API 13 everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
String content = "host=http://sdf3452.domain.com/";


Matcher mm;
Pattern hostP = Pattern.compile("host=([a-z0-9./:]*)");
mm=hostP.matcher(content);
String match = "";
if (mm.find()){//use m.find() first
    match = mm.group(1);//1 is order number of brackets 
}
```

Comment: Since `match` is inside the scope of your `if` statement, this code will throw a compile time error.

Comment: Could you please also include an explanation?